# Generating tags to search for in Flickr API from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, flickr

I'll try to keep this simple and clear. I'm pretty new to using API's but I'm using the Flickr API to search for and display photos on my website based on a certain tag. For a simple, static web page this is quite simple and I've already got it working as intended. This is the jquery script I found to use:

```
$(function() {
var apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY_IS_IN_HERE';
var tag = '%23FFLIVE2014-09-03';
var perPage = '25';
var showOnPage = '6';

$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method='+
    'flickr.photos.search&api_key=' + apiKey + 
    '&tags=' + tag + '&per_page=' + perPage + '&jsoncallback=?', 
function(data){
    var classShown = 'class="lightbox"';
    var classHidden = 'class="lightbox hidden"';

    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, rPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
            + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret;

        var thumbPhotoURL = basePhotoURL + '_s.jpg';
        var mediumPhotoURL = basePhotoURL + '.jpg';

        var photoStringStart = '<a ';
        var photoStringEnd = 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ 
            mediumPhotoURL +'"><img src="' + thumbPhotoURL + '" alt="' + 
            rPhoto.title + '"/></a>;'
        var photoString = (i < showOnPage) ? 
            photoStringStart + classShown + photoStringEnd : 
            photoStringStart + classHidden + photoStringEnd;

        $(photoString).appendTo("#flickr");
    });
    $("a.lightbox").lightBox();
});
```

});

Create a #flickr div on a page and load that script, photos tagged #FFLIVE2014-09-03 would be displayed, if there are any. My problem is that the site/page I want to show the photos on is dynamic with data generated from a database. So website.com/page.php is the single page, in the database is data for a certain date and a performance that happened on it (For a band).

So what I'm struggling with is how to dynamically edit the tags searched for in the script. With the above script placed in my page.php obviously page.php?id=1 and page.php?id=261 will show the same photos, because the tags searched will be the same when in fact they should be different, based on the date for the data.

So, is there some way to do this? Generate the correct date tag to search for based on the database data? I can generate the correct tag inside the PHP file itself quite easily, just echo the first part of the tag then the date. But how would I do that in relation to the javascript? I gather it is possible to use PHP within Javascript but that would be outside the database, so it wouldn't know what it was generating.

I hope that makes sense!